# How do I capture error if Angular2 HTTP response data does not adhere to type

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, typescript-typings, angular-http

If I create an Angular2 HTTP request using types then assign a response also with a specific type and if the server response is not of the type then can I capture the error instead of breaking the application and do an activity?

.... interfaces .....

```
export interface loginUser {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

export interface loginResData {
    username: string;
    details: string;
}
```

... Component Code .....

```
user: loginUser
 constructor(private _httpprovider: Httpprovider, private _router: Router) {

   }

  login(user) {
    this._httpprovider.httpReq(this.url, 'POST', user, null).subscribe((data: loginResData) => {
      this.loginEvent.emit(data);
    });
  }
```

How do I capture error occurring on data not on the type data: loginResData. Is it possible in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are ignored at runtime. You better create a class like

```ts
   export class loginResData {
     username: string;
     details: string;
     constructor(data:any) {
       if(data && data.username && data.details) {
         this.username = data.username;
         this.details = data.details;
       }
       throw 'loginResData is invalid or incomplete';
     }
   }
```

```ts
  login(user) {
    this._httpprovider.httpReq(this.url, 'POST', user, null)
    .map(data:any => new oginResData(data))
    .subscribe((data: loginResData) => {
      this.loginEvent.emit(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ok awesome. Thank you.